# finding avg/min/max for a dataset using mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

i am trying to write a mapreduce sample practice program where in my data set is somthing like this

its about salaries of people in every year in a country/city/state

```
place      year  salary($)
america    2014  60,000
france     2010  40,000
india      2012  20,000
australia  2001  50,000
america    2014  65,000
```

i want output something like this

```
place   year    avg      min        max
america 2014   625000   600000    650000 
france  2010   400000    400000    400000
```

please guide me how can i write a mapreduce program/ any sample program which is already handled such case.
thanks in advance :)

i have tried mapper part 
    public static class Map extends Mapper{

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            Context context)
            throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        String year=null;
        String country =null;
        String amount=null;

          // this will work even if we receive more than 1 line
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(value.toString());
        String line;
        String[] tokens;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            country = tokens[0];
            year = tokens[1];
            amount = (tokens[2]);

            context.write(new Text(country), new Text(year));
            context.write(new Text(year), new Text(amount));
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Where is you code? What have you already tried?

Comment: hi, the issue is in every mapreduce program i have seen that mapper has a key and a value and at reducer it sum's it and display it... where as in my case i have each country has list of values as years and each year has a list amount.... so i am not sure how to work on this multiple key,value pairs.so i am looking for your advice how should i proceed.

Comment: this is something i have tried at my end(edited in question).. i have tried mapper part but completed blank at reducer how to identify each country and year :( please guide me